# Update 2 exact same images source using javascript

Tags: javascript, captcha

I using PHP captcha called Cryptographer captchan.fr site

I need to use 2 captcha on same page but i have problem they do get generated but when i click refresh only first one refreshes, refresh code looks like this.

```
document.images.captcha.src='cryptographp.html?cfg=0&&'+Math.round(Math.random(0)*1000)+1;
```

I tried this code but it only works for first one anyway

```
document.getElementById('captcha').src='cryptographp.html?cfg=0&&'+Math.round(Math.random(0)*1000)+1;
```

Now I wanted to do something like this I added name="captcha" to image but this does not work for some reason can someone help me fix it?

```
document.getElementsByName('captcha').src='cryptographp.html?cfg=0&&+Math.round(Math.random(0)*1000)+1;
```

I also have jquery attached to page if thats easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have more than one element with same ID on page.  That may be why it's only hitting the first one.  If you add a class to both images called "captcha" you can easily do this with jQuery:

```
$('.captcha').attr('src', 'cryptographp.html?cfg=0&&'+Math.round(Math.random(0)*1000)+1);
```

Comment: Did so, added class and used above command it does nothing. 
When i debug with firebug i enter $('.captcha').src and its saying undefined. Yet i have image with class="captcha"

Comment: @Crainer: The code is wrong. Should be `$('.captcha').attr('src', 'value here')`. `$('.captcha')` returns a jQuery object, not a DOM element, so you cannot access its properties. @Kon: Please fix this.

Comment: Doh, such an idiot..  I don't know what I was thinking...  will update.