# Update 2 exact same images source using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Update 2 exact same images source using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958617/update-2-exact-same-images-source-using-javascript)

I using PHP captcha called Cryptographer captchan.fr site

I need to use 2 captcha on same page but I have problem they do get generated but when I click refresh only first one refreshes, refresh code looks like this.

```
document.images.captcha.src='cryptographp.html?cfg=0&&'+Math.round(Math.random(0)*1000)+1;
```

I tried this code but it only works for first one anyway

```
document.getElementById('captcha').src='cryptographp.html?cfg=0&&'+Math.round(Math.random(0)*1000)+1;
```

Now I wanted to do something like this i added name="captcha" to image but this does not work for some reason can someone help me fix it?

```
document.getElementsByName('captcha').src='cryptographp.html?cfg=0&&+Math.round(Math.random(0)*1000)+1;
```

I also have jquery attached to page if thats easier.

I tried to remove id and use class but still this does nothing

```
$('.captcha').src='cryptographp.html?cfg=0&&'+Math.round(Math.random(0)*1000)+1;
```

because saying undefined reference.

Comment: Maybe because `img` elements don't support the `name` attribute. And if they do, `document.getElementsByName('captcha')` will return a **collection** of elements, i.e. you'd have to loop over it.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there! You need to use `.attr` in jQuery, as there is no `.src` method

```
$('.captcha').attr('src', 'cryptographp.html?cfg=0&&'+Math.round(Math.random(0)*1000)+1);
```

Ensure your two `<img>` has the class `captcha`

Answer (score 0):

the correct syntax is

```
$(".captcha").attr('src',"image url")
```